# Java EE E-Commerce Frameworks

Tags: java, model-view-controller

What are the Java EE frameworks for developing e-commerce applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "View", do you really mean "web MVC"?

If yes, there's Struts, Spring MVC, Wicket, Java Server Faces, Seam (JSF + Hibernate) - almost too many to name.

Here's one attempt to do so:

http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks

Comment: I edited your original to better match your stated intent.  Let me know if that's incorrect.

Comment: I found these frameworks (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197183/java-based-ecommerce-framework), but the question are a bit dated. I will use as reference the links you gave me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JSF and facelets are a very good combination if you want component based programming model. JSP+Servlet is a good combination for action oriented programming model. You will be working with html, css and javascript directly most of the times is you are using jsp+servlet.

There are other component oriented frameworks ike GWT, Wicket, Vaadin if you doesn't want to work with css and html. These frameworks also greatly help in testing and debugging the client layer from withing your IDE, which is difficult while working with html,jsp etc directly. You will only work with Java and hence more developer friendly

Comment: I concluded that something is not clear a tool set for each tier MVC. Thanks for reply.